# MongoDB Ops Manager deployment no longer working after environment upgrade and hardening

Tags: mongodb

I am running a small Mongodb replicaset, on prem, via Rocky Linux 8.8.  Recently many environmental changes were made that has made MongoDB Ops Manager unable to monitor or deploy MongoDB's.  On the ops manager dashboard the servers appear red and the download icon just spins forever.

The only meaningful entry in the logs are this:

`[.error] [scr/director/director.go:executePlan:1046] <rs1_5> [15:32:40.996] Postcondition failed for step Download because ['desiredState.FullVersion' is not a member of 'currentState.VersionsOnDisk' ('desiredState.FullVersion'={"trueName": "5.0.18","gitVersion":"796abe56bfdbca6968ff570311bf72d93632825b","modules":null,"major":5,"minor":0,"patch":18}, 'currentState.VersionsOnDisk'=[])]. Outcome=3`

With so many environmental changes, I'm looking for a hint at what could possibly be blocking the mongoDB versions above from appearing to Ops Manager, or some necessary settings that I can convey to our system administrators.

The only similar error I've see was this, with no answer: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/desiredstate-fullversion-is-not-a-member-of-currentstate-versionsondisk/13254

So my question is this: Would any upgrades or server hardening cause the above error to appear?  Or, are there any specific settings Linux/Ops Manager requires to be able to check for current Mongodb versions on disk.

Comment: Can you connect with mongo shell `mongosh`? Did you enable SELinux?

Comment: mongosh works, SELinux is not enabled...thanks!

Comment: When you use MongoDB Ops Manager then you have the Enterprise license, i.e. you have support from MongoDB - open a ticket for it.

Comment: Well that's not helpful...in case anyone else has this issue:

Turns out my issue was permissions to /var on Linux.  I configured the binaries to be stored in another location besides /var/lib/mongodb-mms-automation and it works again.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for this error often stems from the missing dependencies for MongoDB Enterprise Edition.

Kindly ensure that you have verified and installed the necessary third-party dependencies before trying to install MongoDB Enterprise.

Refer to the following documentation for more details: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/ops-manager/current/tutorial/provisioning-prep/#installing-mongodb-enterprise-dependencies.